# How to fix Valgrind "Conditional Jump..." error

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind

So I know there are others with the same problem as me, but unfortunately I'm not getting anyhting solved... So basically I am searching for a key in a hashtable(based on a given word) if not found return NULL, but if found return the value. It repeats itself until there are no more words in the FILE read.

So here is the output of valgrind.

```
    ==877683== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised 
    value(s)
    ==877683==    at 0x4C31258: __strlen_sse2 (in 
    /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==877683==    by 0x401641: _strdup (loesung.c:58)
    ==877683==    by 0x401641: ht_get (loesung.c:212)
    ==877683==    by 0x400E5C: main (loesung.c:513)
    ==877683==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack 
    allocation
    ==877683==    at 0x400B0A: main (loesung.c:325)
```

And here is some of the code...

```
    while((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
        if((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')){   
                ...
        }
        else if(c == 10 || (c >= 32 && c <= 64) || (c >= 91 && c <= 
    96) || (c >= 123 && c <= 126)){
            if(ht_get(dict,word) == NULL){....}         //LINE 513


   int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  //LINE 325 Where the value 
                                        was created apparently... I 
                                        dont get this at all!
   if(argc != 2){
     fprintf(stderr,"...");
     exit(2);
     return 2;
   }
   else {
     wb = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   }
```

And here is the function ht_get...

```
    char *ht_get(HashTable *hashtable, const char *key){
    char *key_cp = NULL;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    List *tmp;

    key_cp = _strdup(key);              //LINE 212
    i = hash(key, hashtable->size);
    tmp = hashtable->array[i];

    while (tmp != NULL) {
            if (str_cmp1(tmp->key, key_cp) == 0) { 
                    break;
            }
            tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    free(key_cp);

    if (tmp == NULL) {
            return NULL;
    }
    return tmp->value;
    }
```

And the _strdup function is the same as strdup, but I had to write it myself as the one in the string.h library would not work.

So what I tried to do was to initialize the variable liek this:

char * getWord;
getWord = strdup(ht_get(dict,word));

as well like:

char *getWord = ht_get(dict,word);

and some other ways that just dont work.
Sorry for the long question.

Comment: The error message seems to clearly indicate that `key` in `ht_get` is derived from an uninitialized variable, which means `word` is uninitialized.

Comment: "*... strdup ... in the string.h library would not work.*" in which sense?

Comment: The problem was indeed that word was not initialized! It was driving me crazy, so thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When scrutinizing these three lines:

```
==877683==    by 0x401641: _strdup (loesung.c:58)
==877683==    by 0x401641: ht_get (loesung.c:212)
==877683==    by 0x400E5C: main (loesung.c:513)
```

And from your code snippets:

```
...
    key_cp = _strdup(key);              //LINE 212
...
            if(ht_get(dict,word) == NULL){....}         //LINE 513
...
```

> Since `key` is the second parameter to `ht_get` and is passed to `_strdup`, then the conclusion is that `word` is uninitialized.

Although you do not show all of your code, it is likely you are building up `word` until you encounter a word separator, and then you call `ht_get`.

> Your logical flaw would be that `word` is not initialized if the very first character encountered is a word separator.

One possible fix would be to establish a flag to indicate whether or not you have created a word. The flag is initialized `false` and becomes `true` whenever a word is being formed, and becomes `false` whenever a word separator is processed.

> ```
> bool have_word = false;
> ...
> while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
>     if (isalpha(c)) {
>         ... make a word
>         have_word = true;
>     } else {
>         if (have_word) {
>             ... process a word
>         }
>         have_word = false;
>     }
> ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks it was indeed that word was not initialized. Establishing the flag was good as well, it worked. Thanks a lot.